# SAS, array code, two indices, dropping records

Tags: arrays, sas

I am looking through some code and wondering what this does. Below are the code comments. I'm still not sure what this code does even with the code comments. I have used arrays but not familiar with this code. It looks like this code dedupes by using two indices. Is that correct? So if there is a combination of CCS_DR_IDX and TXN_IDX, it will delete those records?

Now handle cases where the dollar matches. If ccs_dr_idx has already been used then delete the record. Dropped txns here will be added back in with the claim data called missing.

```
PROC SORT DATA=OUT.REQ_1_9_F_AMT_MATCH; BY CCS_DR_IDX DATEDIF; RUN;

    DATA OUT.REQ_1_9_F_AMT_MATCH_V2;
        SET OUT.REQ_1_9_F_AMT_MATCH;

        ARRAY id_one{40000} id_one1-id_one40000;
        ARRAY id_two{40000} id_two1-id_two40000;

        RETAIN id_one1-id_one40000 id_two1-id_two40000;

        IF _n_=1 then i=1;
        else i+1;

        do j=1 to i;
            if CCS_DR_IDX=id_one{j} then delete;
        end;

        do k = 1 to i;
                if TXN_IDX = id_two{k} then delete;
        end;

        id_one{i}=CCS_DR_IDX;
        id_two{i}=TXN_IDX;

        drop i j k  id_one1-id_one40000 id_two1-id_two40000;

    run;
```

Comment: Looks like it is removing duplicates in variables CSS_DR_IDX and TXN_IDX.  The THEN DELETE; part.  Can you show a bit of the data as text so it can be copied from your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sort is

```
BY CCS_DR_IDX DATEDIF;
```

The *filtering* or *selecting* occurs when control reaches the bottom of the data step and implicitly `OUTPUT`s.  That occurs only if `CCS_DR_IDX` **and** `TXN_IDX` is a combination where neither has appeared previously.

Since you have sorted by `CCS_DR_IDX` you can know there is implicit grouping and there will be at most one record per `CCS_DR_IDX` output, and for the first group it must be the first record in the group. Each successive row in a `CCS_DR_IDX` group, post output, will match an entry in `id_one` and be tossed away by `DELETE`.

When you start processing the next `CCS_DR_IDX` group the rows will be processed until you reach the next distinct `TXN_ID` with respect to those tracked in `id_two`.  Because the sort had a second key `DATDIF` you can say the output is **"a selection of the first occurring combinations of unique pair items `CCS_DR_IDX` `TXN_ID`"** (somewhat akin to pair-sampling without repeats.)

There could be a case where some `CCS_DR_IDX` is not in the output -- that would happen when the group contains only `TX_ID`s that occurred in prior `CCS_DR_IDX`s.

Without seeing the data model and combination reasons (probably some sort of cartesian join) it's hard to make a less vague statement of what is being selected.